# Is there any easy download manager that currently works with tor on a linux machine?

Tags: plugin

Preferable a safe plugin to tor browser.
HK sucks right now and I think it will only get worse.

Answer (score 1):

There are no safe plugins except those that come with Tor Browser because none of the others have been tested to confirm that they are safe.

Personally, I sometimes use torsocks with wget. It's more powerful than a lot of download managers, it just has a higher learning curve. Note: I use Linux so that might not be an option for you unless you want to learn WSL or have a Mac.